# Xorg crashing: ubuntu automatic logout, back to login screen

Tags: xorg, logout

Since a few days ago, my Ubuntu Xorg keeps crashing. At random times, I get automatically logged out and I go back to the login screen.

My Xorg log output is as follows:

```
/var/log/Xorg.1.log.old:[161352.959] (EE) intel(0): Detected a hung GPU, disabling acceleration.
/var/log/Xorg.1.log.old:[161352.959] (EE) intel(0): When reporting this, please include i915_error_state from debugfs and the full dmesg.
```

On Google I couldn't find a workaround. Anyone got an idea to avoid these crashes - either use another Linux distro, another gnome, another GPU driver... ?

Comment: Can you try disabling hardware acceleration in `xorg.conf`?

Comment: How do I do that? (Sorry I'm relatively new to Ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

This is the same problem i GOT once

**Whathappened to your system is:**

You have misconfigured or messedup with xorg while tweaking your system

**Solution**

1. Try to enter with someother user Like Guest if, Yes than
2. Logout guest and press **ctrl+alt+F2** to enter your Terminal mode.
3. Login with your user which has sudo powers
4. Create a new user and add this user to sudo group

`sudo adduser username`

```
sudo adduser username sudo
```

now logout and login with newly created sudo user and delete your messedup user 
thats it.

**Other solution**

1. Install other GUI for system i.e Gnome

goto terminal mode by pressing `ctrl+alt+F2`

**install gnome**

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-panel
```

This will install gnome 3, gnome classic and gnome-classic without effects
to enter gnome on your login screen press unity icon and you will see the list of interfaces to choose from.

HOPE this will help

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out. Is the only thing I need to do, is to copy paste the whole /home/olduser/ directory to /home/newuser/ to have my user completely the same again?

Comment: Just copy your data from old user and save it to pin/USB and when you are done with new user than paste the date in harddriver and you donot have to copy the /home/olduser directory to /home/newuser becasue you will the copy the error also as xorg conf file are in your home directory and different for each user but the are hidden

Comment: Hi, I did this yesterday and the crashes seem to appear less often, however I had one crash today so it didn't solve it completely. Any other solution?

Comment: you might have did something with xorg as root, I suggest you to reinstall or if you dont want than search how to set default values of xorg if doesnot work than install other xorg server that is gnome-3 its better than unity and i use gnome see my answer above how to install gnome-3

Comment: thank you very much, I am sorry for late respond but I'll try this!

Comment: AH! Thank you! I have been wrestling with the fglrx drivers trying to get them to work. Whenever I would log in, regardless of the Desktop Environment, It would boot me back to the LightDM login screen. A new user works just fine!

Answer (score 1):

Check your `~/.xsession-errors` file. For me this was a permission problem - for some reason `~/.dbus`, `~/.gvfs` and `~/.Xauthority` were owned by root. Also some files in `~/.cache`. That isn't supposed to happen (probably a bug). To fix it you can do this:

```
cd
sudo chown -R timmmm:timmmm .* *
rm ~/.Xauthority # May not be necessary but can't hurt.
```

That did it for me anyway.

Comment: My ~/.xsession-errors file says "openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0" Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to reconfigure your .Xorg file? Try this in the terminal by using the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> command. 
After logging in using the userid and password crun the code below.

```
sudo service gdm stop | sudo Xorg -configure | sudo service gdm start
```

I tried the above command, it worked for me, and I was able to login.