# Cant use Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, gnome-terminal, terminal-server

I was using compiz config and now I can't access anything. 
What can I do to fix this? I was thinking restarting the configuration to factory configuration. Is it possible to enter Ubuntu using terminal?

Comment: If you log into the console (CTRL-ALT-F1) you can type `sudo reboot` to reboot your system, but please edit to clarify your question

Comment: Yes, I mean, restarting , rebooting the system configuration.

Comment: Ah, so you want to know how to reboot?

Comment: Yes, but without loosing the data.

Comment: `sudo reboot` will reboot the system (power off and power on), but if you want to restore configurations, you need to restore from a backup.

Comment: Alternatively, you can try reinstalling from the DVD/USB and just not formatting the `/` partition

Comment: I don't have one. Is there a way to undo all the configuration that I made and go back to the factory configuration?

Comment: To my knowledge, not without reinstalling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note: this fix will work only *after* completing the steps outlined in mheadroom's [post](https://askubuntu.com/a/682347/457976).**

From your login screen press and hold  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  +  <kbd>F1</kbd>  to load a non-graphical terminal. If that key combination doesn't work, try  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  +  <kbd>F3</kbd>  instead.

Once in terminal type:

```
sudo apt-get install gdm && sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

Then select gdm and hit  <kbd>Enter</kbd> . Now:

```
sudo shutdown now -r
```

And wait for your system to reboot. Bam! You're done!

Comment: C'MON MAN! Today I lost a full day of work, THANKS TO YOU now my desktop is back!!!

Comment: ...just two more questions... :) I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, how can I go back to the original version? And also, you're a PRO, where do you work? THANKS THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: Since you're unable to access the GUI desktop / are stuck in a login loop, and following up on David Cole's later [post](https://askubuntu.com/a/682371/457976), you can remedy the Compviz misconfiguration by first accessing a Terminal at the login screen by holding  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  +  <kbd>F1</kbd>  (alternatively,  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  +  <kbd>F2</kbd> , or +  <kbd>F3</kbd> ).

Once in Terminal issue the following command to reset Compviz:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

Now, reboot your system by typing:

```
sudo reboot now
```

This should have returned Compviz to its default, post-install state.

Finally, proceed with David Cole's above mentioned instructions to set the default display manager.

*Reference: [How-To-Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/167674/how-to-enable-and-tweak-ubuntus-flashy-graphical-effects/)*

Comment: I can go beyond the users screen. I type my password, it enters but the logs me out.

Comment: How long do you remain logged in for before automatically being logged out? What exactly does the desktop look like for those brief moments? I recommend reviewing some of the contributions in a [similar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/274088/xorg-crashing-ubuntu-automatic-logout-back-to-login-screen) Ask Ubuntu post. In particular, see if you a Guest account is available from the login window. If so, login with that, open a terminal window, and create a new user with: `sudo adduser <some-new-username> sudo`. Assign a password and try accessing and repairing the system that way.

Comment: No longer than 10 seconds, it only looks black.

Comment: I have already tried some things like adding a new user...thanks!

Comment: @acne I made an updated answer for you.